# Journey Builder Wait Time on Attribute

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a journey that has a wait time based on 10 days after `Sold_On` date.  If I enter some backlog records where the `Sold_On` date is 15 days after - will they automatically be pushed through that wait time?

I would assume so, but I wanted to verify because the documentation is lacking.   This is what is says as a info bubble in Journey Builder:
`If the calculated date is in the past, contacts proceed to the next activity`

Comment: I'm keen to hear the results on your testing

Comment: Testing has proved that it will advance. Going live tomorrow - so we shall see the final result.

Comment: What amazes me is that the tooltip matches the actual result!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can confirm that records older than the wait time will be processed without blocking or waiting an additional period. 
We have ca. 500k records going through per week which often have past dates and havent seen any unexpected outcome
Doug